# manually running a scheduled job. LAST_RUN_DATE is not updating

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbms-scheduler

I have a job on the database which runs nightly at 1am using the DBMS scheduler.

I also want to be able to run the job manually whenever I was.

I do this by running

```
execute dbms_scheduler.run_job('JOB_NAME');
```

This all works fine and the job does run, however when i look up the job on **DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS** the **LAST_RUN_DATE** column still only holds the date that the job was last run from the scheduler (at 1am) and not when i manually ran it. Does this make sense to anyone. I want to be able to get the last time the job was run so I can show the user running it.

This is the query where I'm looking up the **LAST_RUN_DATE**,

```
SELECT LAST_START_DATE 
   FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS 
WHERE job_name='JOB_NAME';
```

My work around is to use this to get the last date but it doesn't seem right:

```
select log_date, job_name, status, run_duration
  from dba_scheduler_job_run_details 
where job_name='JOB_NAME'
```

Comment: "it doesn't seem right":  please elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The optional parameter use_current_session on dbms_scheduler.run_job defaults to TRUE when it is omitted.  Setting this parameter to FALSE will update last_start_date:

```
execute dbms_scheduler.run_job('JOB_NAME', use_current_session => false);
```

However, you may have other side effects as a result by setting this parameter.  Refer to the Oracle docs for your specific Oracle version for more details.

[12.1 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72395)  (emphasis mine):

> use_current_session:
>
> This specifies whether or not the job run should occur in the same
>   session that the procedure was invoked from.The job always runs as the
>   job owner, in the job owner's schema, unless it has credential
>   specified, then the job runs using the user named in the credential.
>
> When use_current_session is set to TRUE:
>
> You can test a job and see any possible errors on the command line.
>
> **state, run_count, last_start_date, last_run_duration, and
>   failure_count of *_scheduler_jobs are not updated.**
>
> RUN_JOB can be run in parallel with a regularly scheduled job run.
>
> When use_current_session is set to FALSE:
>
> You need to check the job log to find error information. **All relevant
>   fields in *_scheduler_jobs are updated.** RUN_JOB fails if a regularly
>   scheduled job is running.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.